# Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree with nested Navigator

Tags: flutter, dart, navigator

I am working with nested navigators for multiple sections in my app and I have defined the keys for these navigators, you can see below the code where I have added Navigator keys in class so i can use it in my project by accessing class

```
class NavigatorKeys {
static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> homeNavigatorKey =
  GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: "homeNavigatorKey");
static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> shiftNavigatorKey =
  GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: "shiftNavigatorKey");
static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> requestNavigatorKey =
  GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: "requestNavigatorKey");
static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> messageNavigatorKey =
  GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: "messageNavigatorKey");
static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> profileNavigatorKey =
  GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: "ProfileNavigatorKey");
}
```

Below is the code for one of the sections i.e ProfileNavigator which uses key

```
import '/theme/styles.dart';
import '/utils/constants.dart';
import '/views/profile/balances_page.dart';
import '/views/profile/change_password_page.dart';
import '/views/profile/language_page.dart';
import '/views/profile/profile_page.dart';
import '/views/profile/test_page.dart';
import '/views/profile/wage_accounts.dart';
import '/widgets/page_route_builder.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProfileNavigator extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProfileNavigator({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator(
      key: NavigatorKeys.profileNavigatorKey,
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
        switch (settings.name) {
          case '/':
            return pageRouteBuilder(
              ProfilePage(),
            );
          case '/langPage':
            return pageRouteBuilder(
              LanguagePage(),
            );
          case '/changePass':
            return pageRouteBuilder(
              ChangePasswordPage(),
            );
          case '/balancePage':
            return pageRouteBuilder(
              BalancesPage(),
            );
          case '/testPage':
            return pageRouteBuilder(
              TestPage(),
            );
          case '/balancePage':
            return pageRouteBuilder(
              BalancesPage(),
            );
          case '/wageAccounts':
            return pageRouteBuilder(
              WageAccountsPage(),
            );
        }

        return pageRouteBuilder(
          Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                "Hmm...Thats Weird",
                style: kTextStyleLargeBlack,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

here is my implementation for BottomBar

```
List<Widget> mobilePages = [
    HomeNavigator(),
    GetConfigurationProvider().getConfigurationModel.shiftEnabled? ShiftNavigator():null,
    RequestNavigator(),
    GetConfigurationProvider().getConfigurationModel.messagesEnabled?MessageNavigator():null,
    ProfileNavigator(),
  ];

  Widget _bottomNavigatorBar() {
    return Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        // sets the background color of the `BottomNavigationBar`
        canvasColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        // sets the active color of the `BottomNavigationBar` if `Brightness` is light
      ),
      child: BottomBar(
          height: Platform.isIOS ? 90 : 60,
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
          items: <BottomBarItem>[
            BottomBarItem(
                title: Text(pagesInfoList[0].pageName),
                icon: Icon(pagesInfoList[0].pageIcon),
                activeColor: Colors.white,
                inactiveColor: Colors.grey[300]),
            BottomBarItem(
                title: Text(pagesInfoList[1].pageName),
                icon: Icon(pagesInfoList[1].pageIcon),
                activeColor: Colors.white,
                inactiveColor: Colors.grey[300]),
            BottomBarItem(
                title: Text(pagesInfoList[2].pageName),
                icon: Icon(pagesInfoList[2].pageIcon),
                activeColor: Colors.white,
                inactiveColor: Colors.grey[300]),
            BottomBarItem(
                title: Text(pagesInfoList[3].pageName),
                icon: Icon(pagesInfoList[3].pageIcon),
                activeColor: Colors.white,
                inactiveColor: Colors.grey[300]),
            BottomBarItem(
                title: Text(pagesInfoList[4].pageName),
                icon: Icon(pagesInfoList[4].pageIcon),
                activeColor: Colors.white,
                inactiveColor: Colors.grey[300]),
          ],
          selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
          onTap: (int index) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedIndex = index;
            });
          }),
    );
  }
```

And below code I used for android back button to work

```
  List<GlobalKey<NavigatorState>> _navigatorKeys = [
    NavigatorKeys.homeNavigatorKey,
    NavigatorKeys.shiftNavigatorKey,
    NavigatorKeys.requestNavigatorKey,
    NavigatorKeys.messageNavigatorKey,
    NavigatorKeys.profileNavigatorKey,
  ];

 Future<bool> _systemBackButtonPressed() {
    if (_navigatorKeys[_selectedIndex].currentState.canPop()) {
      _navigatorKeys[_selectedIndex]
          .currentState
          .pop(_navigatorKeys[_selectedIndex].currentContext);
    } else {
      SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod<void>('SystemNavigator.pop');
    }
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _systemBackButtonPressed,
  ..........
```

So what happens is when I logout the user and Login again I start getting error of Duplicate Global Key detected it mostly initiates in ProfileNavigator, and then debug console keep showing the message of Duplicate Global key in infinite times

[image]

[image]

on Logout this is the code that take user to Login Page start of t

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (_) => LoginPage(),
                  ),
                );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Logout code, you have to use pushReplacement() instead of push(), because it will clear the stack and you will not get a duplicate key error in your widget tree.

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (_) => LoginPage(),
              ),
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (_) => LoginPage(),
                  ),
                );
```

Places the new Scaffold on top of the previous.  You can't push a 2nd duplicate Scaffold as a third layer when you want to return to the original screen, instead use:

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

That removes the 2nd screen, and you just see the original, never really left 1st screen. If you don't want to keep the original screen under the 2nd, use

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (_) => LoginPage(),
              ),
            );
```